# Passing data from enum to sheet triggered inside ForEach loop

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, enums, swiftui

I've got an ForEach loop inside my VStack, so that for every element in my enum a new "cell" is created. This works just fine. I can pass the title and the number for each cell, but in each cell there is a button which is toggling a sheet view. Each sheet should contain the according text in a scroll view. The text therefore is also given in the enum.

**Problem: But when I'm trying to pass that infoText via the element.infoText for every sheet the infoText of the first element in the enum gets presented.**

The ForEach loop:

```
struct ListView: View{

@State var infoSheetIsPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View{

    VStack {
        ForEach(WelcomeCardViewContent.allCases, id: \.self) {
        element in
            HStack {

                Text(element.text)

                Button(action: {
                        self.infoSheetIsPresented.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$infoSheetIsPresented) {
                        Text(element.infoText)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is my enum. Of course there's the InfoSheetView as well, but like i said its basically just a scroll view with text. The text gets passed with a simple "text" constant. For simplicity I've replaced the separate sheet view with a simple text view -> same problem.

```
enum WelcomeCardViewContent: String, CaseIterable{

case personalData
case bodyParameters

var text: String {
    switch self{
    case .personalData:
        return "Personal Data"
    case .bodyParameters:
        return "Body Parameters"
    }
}

var infoText: String {
    switch self{
    case .personalData:
        return "1 Lorem ipsum dolor.."
    case .bodyParameters:
        return "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your advice ^^.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could break down your code, it's hard to spot errors when there's that much unrelated code.

Comment: ...and even more: if you post lots of code - it should at least be compilable and reproduce the error so we can test it. but we for sure don't want to read 10 pages of code which isn't compilable at all....and where lots of things are missing. please read and consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thx tried to shorten everything. Should be compilable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were losing track of the current card, I fixed this by saving the card which is going to be shown. Now the text is displayed correctly.

Here is the fixed version:

```
struct ListView: View {

    @State private var infoSheetIsPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var showingCard: WelcomeCardViewContent = .personalData

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(WelcomeCardViewContent.allCases, id: \.self) { element in
            HStack {
                Text(element.text)

                Button(action: {
                    self.showingCard = element
                    self.infoSheetIsPresented.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "info.circle")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$infoSheetIsPresented) {
                    Text(self.showingCard.infoText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```